# How to get information from a CSV file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, csv, export-to-csv

I have a .CSV file with rows for [ID], [NAME], [LASTNAME], [EMAIL], [GENDER]. There are 1000 entries.

Out of those five rows I have to:

1. Find the total of people on the list. (using a for loop?)
2. Show the first 10 names (name, lastname).
3. Show 3 RANDOM names.
4. Only display emails. (Doable with the current code)
5. Display the first letters of their last name.
6. Add a random number behind their last name.

Can someone make an example, please?

As a Java beginner I really can't seem to find an answer to this. I have searched everywhere and i think im going crazy.

I have imported the .csv file to my java eclipse, using the following code, currently it only displays the ID's.

```
package test;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test111 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName="test.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        inputStream.next();
        while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
            String data = inputStream.next();
            String[] values = data.split(",");
            
            System.out.println(values[0]);
            
        }
        inputStream.close();
        System.out.println("e");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        


            
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is printing the first element of the array. This is where i ran out of ideas..

Comment: Maybe you can find some libraries to process cvs files?

Answer (score 2):

In order to take every value you have to do something like this:

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
String name = values[1];
String lastName = values[2];
String email = values[3];
String gender = values[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours is a lesson in why you shouldn't blindly copy code without reading it, researching it and understanding it.

Look at line 15 from your own code. What do you think is going on here?

```
String[] values = data.split(",");
```

You've read a line from your CSV file into a field called `data` and now you're calling the `.split` method with a comma as a parameter to break up that line into tokens wherever it finds a comma. Those tokens are being placed into the cells of an array called `values`.

Why are you only getting your ID attribute? Look at this line:

```
System.out.println(values[0]);
```

We just established that all tokens have been placed in an array called `values`. Let's look at the attribute key you provided:

> [ID], [NAME], [LASTNAME], [EMAIL], [GENDER]

Hmm... if printing `values[0]` gives us the ID, I wonder what we'd get if we... oh, I don't know... maybe tried to print from a different element in the array?

Try:

```
System.out.println(values[1]);
System.out.println(values[2]);
System.out.println(values[3]);
System.out.println(values[4]);
```

See what you get.

Coding is about trying things in order to learn them. Knowledge doesn't magically become embedded in your head. To learn something, you have to practice repeatedly, and in doing so, you're going to make mistakes -- this is just how it goes. Don't give up so easily.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. I think I must have somehow gotten the story confusing. I can print out all the "values".
But i cannot count the values in each row (using .length()) for some reason, i only seem to get the full list of the ID's. I only need the total number or the last one..

Basically,  I need a way to not display all of the table when printing, but instead like show only first 10 or 3 random.

Comment: You can't get the length that way because `.length()` is for ArrayList. For array, you use `array.length` where array is the name of your array. See? No parentheses. Now it seems you're asking a second question, which means you should post it as a second question. If my answer satisfied the first question, click the checkmark next to it to let people know what worked and then post your next question.